# ffmpeg mjpeg pixel_format does not work with avfoundation

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, mjpeg

I'm capturing a video using a webcam that supports streaming its output as mjpeg. So far I've been doing it successfully on linux as follows:

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video4 ...
```

However, I'm deploying my application on Mac and don't seem to find an alternative with avfoundation.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format mjpeg -i /dev/video4 ...
```

returns and error saying that mjpeg is not recognized.

Streaming the video uncompressed limits the resolution that my application is able to process (downstream processing is quite intensive). Is there any way to read mjpeg from the webcam on Mac?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you were trying to develop this under macOS Monterey. Big Sur still had MJPEG compatibility (could try downgrading if that helps?), but Monterey seems to have removed this support from USB devices. I have not yet tried Ventura but I suspect it will be the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).